# Can you know child name in inherent?

Tags: php

I have a clase Base in PHP for inherit it to many children classes, managing errors into Base class, I try to print in screen where the error occurs, Can I get the child class name to show in the error during the Exception in Base parent Class?

Comment: You can use `get_class( $this );` ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)) in the base class - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: The problem here is, I am calling Base but Ext  does not extend From Base. and I need the name of the class who is calling to base, in this case is Ext. this is posible?

Comment: Yes. Can you add a little snippet of code to show us how exactly you are calling this Base class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using [get_class()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)

```
class Base{
    public function printBase(){
        echo get_class($this);
    }
}

class Ext extends Base{}

$ext = new Ext();
$ext->printBase(); //Output: Ext
```

Comment: I use get_class in parent like Base class in your example. The result was "Base". Iam doing something wrong?

Comment: The problem here is, I am calling Base but Ext does not extend From Base. and I need the name of the class who is calling to base, in this case is Ext. this is posible?

Answer (score 0):

The function get_called_class() resolve my problem, this throws the name of the class who is calling. http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-called-class.php